# differential equation solving by integration method taking limit.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, complex-integration

> \begin{align}
> \frac{dQ(t)}{dt}&=w\cdot P(t) \tag{1}\\
> \frac{dP(t)}{dt}&=-w\cdot Q(t)+g\cdot \text{Mod}(A(t))^2 \tag{2}\\
> \frac{dA(t)}{dt}&=-(k-i\cdot(1+n\cdot \cos(at)))A(t)\\&\quad+i\cdot g\cdot A(t)Q(t)+E(1+n\cdot \cos(bt))-iA1(t) \tag{3}\\
> \end{align}

I am trying to solve these three equations by integration method taking limit 0 to 50a. but unable to solve.
if anybody can solve it most welcome. Sorry for the code, i was not able to write in correct way, i hope you will not find any difficulty to understand my question.

Comment: I've tried rewriting the differential equation, but the last term $iA1(t)$ doesn't seem right. Moreover, what do you mean by Mod? And what are $k,i,w,g,E,a,b$

Comment: these are constant